# How to output current value of flags register Z80?

Tags: assembly, embedded, z80

I want to debug my program, but I need to know the value of the flags register,
but im stuck figuring out the instructions to do so. For z80 processor.

[My only guess is to use jp *, nn and then set bits in register A depending on the jumps to test the conditions, but surely theres a much simpler way but i just can't see it]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can push `AF` and then pop it to any of: `BC`, `DE` or `HL`, from where you can extract the flags state.